# Neo4j - deleting a pattern label takes forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I run this:

```
MATCH (b:Bisac) WHERE (b.bisac_code =~ '.*000000') SET b:Main;
```

And now I want to delete the nodes labeled as Main.
The query

```
match (m:Main)-[r]-() delete r, m;
```

Takes forever and there are only 52 nodes to be deleted.
What I am doing wrong here?

And while these delete never completes, no other query returns. Looks like the db engine is no longer responding.

And after a while fails like this:

```
match (m:Main)-[r]-() delete r, m;
Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

To be mentioned again: while this was running endless, no other query was returning and no other session was possible to be open.
Apparently the database works like a single-user/single-connection/single-thread system.

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you running?

Comment: Another thing is to put `EXPLAIN` on the front of your query to see what Neo4j plans do do with it (assuming you're running version 2.2.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following parameters in the neo4j-wrapper.conf file.

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=10240
wrapper.java.maxmemory=10240
```

I also deleted everything and reloaded without that SET Main.
Which I will never use it again since it is not clear how to eliminated when is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is maybe make sure there's only 52:

```
MATCH (m:Main) RETURN count(m)
```

Beyond that, you might try this query:

```
MATCH (m:Main) OPTIONAL MATCH m-[r]-() DELETE r, m;
```

Though I'm not quite sure why the other one would demand so many resources.

Comment: Did so but I ended up with deleting also all b:Bisac nodes.

Comment: I also used LIMIT and repeated the statement until done.

Comment: How many paths where it? I.e. `match (m:Main)-[r]-() return count(*) ` ?

Comment: if there are many relationships (millions) connected to your main nodes you can use limits `MATCH (m:Main) WITH m LIMIT 10 OPTIONAL MATCH m-[r]-() DELETE r, m;`

Comment: Two millions relationships. I deleted using LIMIT. However the deletion removed also the initial relationships existent like match (b: Bisac) - [ r ] - ( )

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would try to separate relations and nodes removal, running two separate queries:

```
match (m:Main)-[r]-() delete r;
match (m:Main) delete m;
```

Not sure if it is a good idea, but I suspect Neo4j has to postpone deletion of relations in your first query type and mark somehow relation as "to_be_deleted". With so many relations in your DB it may cause problems.

But as I said, I'm far away from beeing sure, it's rather a speculation...